# Seeked event - tolerance

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to know the average "time-lost" (tolerance) in the seeked event.

e.g. `video.currentTime = 50`, but we may have timeupdate lost (timeupdate event) "*250ms*", so, it is a possibility to seek to "*50.250s*", and I don't know if we can lose more time or not e.g. if we run the code in old or bad device.

I tried in the new devices and the time update was instant, but I have to be sure for the bad devices.